# Recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, computer-science, backtracking

I need help with this exercise:
Give the pseudo-code that receives in input an integer n and prints the all possible matrices nxn where the a are above b and b are above c.
For example with n=2: (the order isn't important)

> output: 
>   aa aa aa ab ab bb aa aa ac cc bb bb bc bc ab ab ac 
>   aa ab bb ab bb bb ac cc ac cc bc cc bc cc bc cc bc

The algorithm's complexity would be O(n^2∗S(n)). Where S(n) is the number of matrix that should be printed, and n^2 is the printing time.
I've developed this code...but i think that is wrong...

```
public class EsercizioNovBT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=2 , i , j;
        char[][] m = new char [n][n];
        boolean[] isBR = new boolean [n];
        boolean[] isBC = new boolean [n];
        boolean[] isCR = new boolean [n];
        boolean[] isCC = new boolean [n];
        boolean[] isAC= new boolean [n];
        boolean[] isAR = new boolean [n];

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            isBR[i]=false;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            isBC[i]=false;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            isCR[i]=false;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            isCC[i]=false;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            isAR[i]=false;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            isAC[i]=false;
        for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
            for(j=0 ; j<n ;j++)
                m[i][j]='d';
        i=0;j=0;
        scriviSuM(m,isBR,isBC,isCR,isCR,i,j,n);



    }



    static void scriviSuM(char[][]M , boolean[] isRB,boolean[] isCB,boolean[] isRC,boolean[] isCC,int i, int j , int n)
    {
        if(i==n)
        {
            for (int r=0 ; r<n ; r++)
            {
                for(int c=0 ; c<n ;c++)
                {
                    System.out.print(M[r][c]);
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            if(j==n)
            {
                j=0;
                scriviSuM(M,isRB,isCB,isRC,isCC,i+1,j,n);
            }
            else
            {

                    if (! (isRC[i]) && !(isCC[j]))
                    {
                        if( ! (isRB[i]) && !(isCB[j]) )  // se non ci sono già delle b allora puoi prendere a
                        {
                            M[i][j]='a';
                            scriviSuM(M,isRB,isCB,isRC,isCC,i,j+1,n);
                        }

                        isRB[i]=isCB[j]=true;
                        M[i][j]='b';
                        scriviSuM(M,isRB,isCB,isRC,isCC,i,j+1,n);
                    }
                    isRC[i]=isCC[j]=true;
                    M[i][j]='c';
                    scriviSuM(M,isRB,isCB,isRC,isCC,i,j+1,n);
            }
        }
    }
```

> the output of that is : 
>  aa
>  aa
>
> aa
>  ab
>
> aa
>  ac
>
> aa
>  bc
>
> aa
>  cc
>
> ab
>  cc
>
> ac
>  cc
>
> bc
>  cc
>
> cc
>  cc

Comment: please show us the pseudo-code

Comment: I posted the java code...

Comment: still want an answer?